# How can i display list the connected clients in Websocket on .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, websocket

I made websocket app with console application in .net.

Program.cs :

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Fleck;

namespace WebSocketConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
            var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
            var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:7080");
            server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("İstemci bağlantısı başarılı!");
                    allSockets.Add(socket);
                    Console.WriteLine("Mevcut istemci sayısı: " + allSockets.ToList().Count);
                };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("İstemci bağlantısı koptu!");
                    allSockets.Remove(socket);
                    Console.WriteLine("Mevcut istemci sayısı: " + allSockets.ToList().Count);
                };
                // Mesaj Teslim Alındığında
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
                };
            });

            //giriş mesajını oku
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            //When the message is not "exit", enter an infinite loop
            while (input != "exit")
            {
                //Tüm soket istemcilerini dolaş ve her istemciye mesaj gönder
                foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
                {
                    socket.Send(input);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

htmlpage.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>Mesaj Gönder:</div>
 <input type="text" id="msgContent" />
 <input type="button" value="Gönder" onclick="CHAT.chat()" />
 <div>Gönderilen Mesaj:</div>
 <div id="receiveMsg" style="background-color: gainsboro;"></div>
 <script type="application/javascript">

          window.CHAT = {
              socket: null,
              init: function() {
                  if (window. WebSocket) {
                      CHAT.socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7080/ws");//websocket server address and port
                      CHAT.socket.onopen = function() {
                          console.log("Bağlantı başarıyla kuruldu...");
                      },
                      CHAT.socket.onclose = function() {
                          console.log("Bağlantı kesildi...");
                      },
                      CHAT.socket.onerror = function() {
                          console.log("Bir hata oluştu...");
                      },
                      CHAT.socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                          console.log("Received message: " + e.data);
                          var receiveMsg = document. getElementById("receiveMsg");
                          var html = receiveMsg. innerHTML;
                          receiveMsg.innerHTML = html + "<br/>" + e.data;
                      }
                  } else {
                      alert("Bu taryacı websocket protokolünü desteklemiyor...");
                  }
              },
              chat: function() {
                  var msg = document. getElementById("msgContent");
                  CHAT.socket.send(msg.value);

              }
          };

          CHAT.init();

 </script>
```

How can i display the list of connected clients with dropdown list? Where can i list the connected clients. I tried searching the internet and tried it but I couldn't figure it out.

Also, can we separate clients by device type? For example android, ios, windows, macOs, ubuntu

Comment: You can tell device by looking at ARP table.  From cmd.exe use >ARP -A.  The MAC will tell the type of ethernet card.  Every Ethernet card has a unique MAC which contains manufacturer, model, serial number of the Ethernet Card.  You can get ARP Table with c# code also.  The code to get connections and MAC is easier in Power Shell than in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Winforms or other item types with dropdown list to create the server. Here is an example of using Winforms to create the server:

1. Create a windows forms App project (I'm using the .netframework version):

[image]

2. Pull a ComboBox

[image]

[image]

3. The code is as follows:

   ```
   namespace WebSocketCombox
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public void StartWebSocketServer()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
                var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
                var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:7080");
                server.Start(socket =>
                {
                    string clientUrl = socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress + ":" + socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientPort;
                    socket.OnOpen = () =>
                    {
                        allSockets.Add(socket);
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(clientUrl);

                    };
                    socket.OnClose = () =>
                    {
                        allSockets.Remove(socket);
                        comboBox1.Items.Remove(clientUrl);
                    };
                    // When a message is received
                    socket.OnMessage = message =>
                    {
                        allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
                    };
                });
            });
        }


        public  Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            StartWebSocketServer();
        }
    }
   ```

   }
4. Start the server project.
5. Start the client project

In this way, you will find that the IP address and port number of the client are added to the ComboBox

[image]

If you want it to display the device type, you can refer to jdweng's opinion.